# Find e Replace em bash

Tags: bash, csv, shell-script, replace

Preciso achar linhas desatualizadas em um arquivo csv e substitui-las por linhas novas.

Esses são os comandos que acham as linhas que vão ser substituídas(antigas) e que vão substituir(novas).

```
linhas_antigas=$(diff -y arquivo_com_linhas_antigas.csv arquivo_com_linhas_novas.csv | grep -e "|" | awk -F"|" '{ print $1 }')
linhas_novas=$(diff -y arquivo_com_linhas_antigas.csv arquivo_com_linhas_novas.csv | grep -e "|" | awk -F"|" '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/\t *//')
```

Depois executo o seguinte trecho para fazer o replace:

```
while read -r arquivo_antigo 
do
    echo ${arquivo_antigo//"$linhas_antigas"/"$linhas_novas"} 
done < arquivo_com_linhas_antigas.csv
```

Agora o problema... Quando o diff retorna apenas uma linha entre os dois arquivos, o replace é feito tranquilamente. Mas se tem duas ou mais linhas para serem atualizadas, ele não faz o replace de nenhuma delas.

Imagino que se as variáveis `$linhas_antigas` e `$linhas_novas` fossem arrays facilitaria o processo.

Mas como fazer isso? Tem alguma outra solução??

Comment: Coloque alguns exemplos das linhas. Já fiz algo parecido, aguardo exemplos de linhas.

Comment: Antiga: _Gabriel Hardoim;10;52;3_ Nova: _Gabriel Hardoim;12;55;3_

Comment: Os arquivos `.CSV` sempre vão possuir a mesma quantidade linhas/registros ? Se a linha correspondente não existir, ele deverá ser removida ? A ordem dos registros importa ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo oque entendi seria como atualizar um arquivo de backup.
Conteúdo do arquivo 1:

```
A1 B1;10;52;3
A2 B2;12;52;3
A3 B3;10;52;3
A4 B4;10;34;3
A5 B5;10;52;3
A6 B6;10;33;3
A7 B7;08;52;4
```

Conteúdo arquivo 2:

```
A1 B1;10;52;1
A2 B2;12;52;2
A3 B3;10;52;3
A4 B4;10;34;3
A5 B5;10;52;5
A6 B6;10;33;6
A7 B7;08;52;4
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Quantidade de linhas para determinar quantas vezes o laço sera executado
# Poderia ser com "while" dizendo "enquanto o arquivo for diferente um do outro faça"
qt=$(diff -y --suppress-common-lines l1.csv l2.csv | wc -l)
for (( i = 0; i < $qt; i++ )); do
    # Pega sempre a primeira ocorrência, linhas diferentes
    linha=$(diff -y --suppress-common-lines l1.csv l2.csv | head -n1)
    # Pega a linha antiga
    la=$(awk '{print $1,$2}' <<< $linha)
    # Linha nova
    ln=$(awk '{print $4,$5}' <<< $linha)
    # Coloca o conteúdo do arquivo na variável
    arq=$(cat l1.csv)
    # Faz a substituição da linha antiga pela nova
    arq=${arq//$la/$ln}
    # Coloca a alteração dentro do arquivo original
    echo "$arq" > l1.csv
done
```

Saída:

```
A1 B1;10;52;1
A2 B2;12;52;2
A3 B3;10;52;3
A4 B4;10;34;3
A5 B5;10;52;5
A6 B6;10;33;6
A7 B7;08;52;4
```

Esse método acima faz a alteração linha a linha, se entendi bem, e vc quer atualizar um arquivo levando em consideração outro arquivo, poderia fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -n $(diff -q l1.csv l2.csv) ]]; then
    cat l2.csv > l1.csv
fi
```

Seu script não estava dando certo pq vc colocou todas as linhas diferentes dentro da variável, vc tem que fazer isso linha a linha, por isso que quando tinha apenas uma linha diferente dava certo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode implementar um *script* em `gawk` para processar seus arquivos, por exemplo:

```
BEGIN{
}

{
    if( FNR == NR )
    {
        a[FNR] = $0;
        next;
    }

    print (a[FNR] == $0) ? a[FNR] : $0;
}

END{
}
```

Ou, em uma linha:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR]==$0?a[FNR]:$0}' antigas.csv novas.csv
```

Assumindo que os arquivos `.CSV` de entrada sejam algo como:

**antigas.csv**:

```
JESUS DE NAZARE;15;21;1
MARIA MAGDALENA;12;52;3
JOAO DE DEUS;33;52;5
MATUZALEM DA COSTA;10;34;7
MICHAEL JACKSON;10;28;2
DINO DA SILVA SAURO;16;32;4
FULANO DE TAL;84;25;6
```

**novas.csv**:

```
JESUS DE NAZARE;15;21;8
MARIA MAGDALENA;12;52;3
JOAO DE DEUS;33;52;5
MATUZALEM DA COSTA;15;34;7
MICHAEL JACKSON;10;28;2
DINO DA SILVA SAURO;14;32;9
FULANO DE TAL;84;25;6
```

Saída:

```
JESUS DE NAZARE;15;21;8
MARIA MAGDALENA;12;52;3
JOAO DE DEUS;33;52;5
MATUZALEM DA COSTA;15;34;7
MICHAEL JACKSON;10;28;2
DINO DA SILVA SAURO;14;32;9
FULANO DE TAL;84;25;6
```